# convert text post into xml file using python in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-inventor

newbie here in need of help.

Using App Inventor amd App Engine.  Learning python as i go along. Still early days. Need to post text data from AI to app engine, save in blob store as file (.xml), to be emailed as an attachment.

Am able to send pictures using Shival Wolfs wolfwebmail2, and am sure with a bit of playing with the code i can change it to save the text post as a file in blob store to do the same operation.

As stated newbie learning fast.

Many thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: thanks for the reply. have just managed by more luck than judgement to achieve what i was trying to achieve. with no code change. how do i tag this as solved?

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer. Hopefully this would help others with the same problem! :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was to do nothing with shival wolfs code on app engine, and to replace the 'postfile' block in the app inventor code with a 'posttext' block with the text you want to send attached to it. Also change the filename variable to the name you want the file called including file type (i.e.  .xml, .csv, .txt etc). This appears to work for me.